# Query wordpress custom post type when the Post type has Multiple Words

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a `custom post type` named `What We Do` registered as below,

```
function cp_what_we_do() {
    register_post_type('What We Do', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'What We Do',
            'singular_name' => 'wwd',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Item',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit WWD Item',
        ),
        'description' => 'What We Do',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'supports' => array('title','editor')
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'cp_what_we_do');
```

And I query the above custom post like,

```
$args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type'   => 'What We Do',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => $countNo
        );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The above query returns **No Posts**. But the same process is applied for the post type `services` and it works perfectly. When I have multiple words to the `post_type` (`What We Do`) the query returns no values. Please, someone elaborate on this issue.

Comment: You need to change the post type slug like `what-we-do`. Post type key - Must not exceed 20 characters and may only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes, and underscores.

Comment: Upvoted @Nilambar and as an addition to his answer, I am adding [this codex link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) which should tell you exactly what each parameter is meant to do.